# How to change UIPickerView text colour to white in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if anyone knew how to change the UIPickerView text colour to white. My code is below:

Code:

```
(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    [self.pickerView setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor WhiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %c", 65+row]; // ASCII 65 is "A"
return label;
}


Got it Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView)
    {
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [tView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [tView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"font-name-here" size:15]];
        [tView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }
    // Fill the label text here
    return tView;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There is one delegate method through which you can achieve desired output.

**Objective-C:**

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *strTitle = @"YourTitle";
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strTitle attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

    return attString;

}
```

**Swift:**

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let strTitle = "YourTitle"   
    let attString = NSAttributedString(string: strTitle, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()])
    return attString
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate method:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *title = @"sample title";
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

return attString;

}
```